# After updating from Angular 5 to 6 I keep getting the error: can't resolve timers in xml2js

Tags: angular, npm, angular5, angular6, xml2js

Like the title say, I keep on getting this weird error. I also tried uninstalling it by using npm uninstall xml2js but nothing has worked until now.

[image]

Comment: [Potentially relevant bug](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/issues/301) from the `node-xml2js` project.

Comment: https://update.angular.io/ this guide tells you what you need to alter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fixed this by doing `npm install events buffer stream timers --save`. But I think installing only timers should also work.

**EDIT**

It seems that streams and timers needed to be updated, and not events and buffers

Comment: I needed both timers and stream but not events or buffer.

Comment: Yes, only stream and timers are needed, not events and buffer.

Comment: @BrianM I was just tempted to do it, but it might be worth updating this answer to just note that `npm install stream timers --save` is the only thing that's necessary, based upon the comments and what I just experienced.